# What is the order of checking the $_SESSION variable?

Tags: php, session-variables, session-cookies

In php I want to check if the user is logged in. Usualy it is done like this

```
if (isset($_SESSION['user_name'])
```

The question is. Is it necessary to start session ( write `session_start()` in the code ) before this check? Or is it possible to check session var without starting a session?

Comment: Ideally, yes. It is really necessary to have `session_start();` before using any `$_SESSION['']`, in fact it is mandatory. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you see all the answer there is no way to get the `session variables` without using the `session_start()`

then it is must to use `session_start()` before checking any session variable,
also if you using `if(isset($_SESSION['username']))` it will only work when you start the session before

Answer (score 2):

It is a must that you call `session_start()` before using sessions.

Answer (score 1):

You should call `session_start()` first thing (before you send any content to the browser, even whitespace) and before you use the session. I'm sure that's what the manual says too.

You need it on all pages that use the session.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call session_start() OR session.auto_start to true.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.auto-start

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php